# PHP while statement give me error if database has no results

Tags: php, mysql

PHP while statement give me error if database has no results. Why can't it just not execute if it sees nothing in the database

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_tomorrow)) {
       $rowsB[] = $row['last'];
}
```

The error I get is undefined variable $rowsB. When I put something in the database everything works fine. I also tried wrapping the while loop in an if statement

```
if(results){
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_tomorrow)) {
            $rowsB[] = $row['last'];
            }
}
```

this didn't work either

Comment: Where does `$results` come from? What is it?

Comment: for sure it is a notice and not an error. You should declare your Variable (just say it is an array) or just check result of your query with mysqli_num_rows() function.

Comment: When you create a Stack Overflow question, **ALWAYS** copy any error messages in their entirety and paste them into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result_tomorrow) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_tomorrow)) {
        $rowsB[] = $row['last'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is it an error or notice ? You should define your variable before while loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error only when the query returns no results, then it's because you are trying to use `$rowsB` at a later point without declaring it (pay attention to what line # the error is for). You should always check if the result of the query is valid too:

```
$rowsB = array();
if ($result_tomorrow) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_tomorrow)) {
       $rowsB[] = $row['last'];
    }
}
```

Comment: declare the variable as an array is right (the notice will not show up anymore).

Comment: Declaring the variable first from outside the while loop was correct.  It was something that I needed to do.. however the if statement was not working.

Answer (score -1):

First check if the database returned something then execute your while statement.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); //execute the query

if( $result ){ //on successful query execution
 if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){ //check for number of returned rows. If its > 0
   while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ //execute for loop
    //other statements
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why would a `while` loop work any differently if there were rows in the result set?